# go_router , how to pass parameter as bool or int with query parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

here is how  i pass parameter as queryParameter , it accept all types , <String, dynamic> :

```
routes.goNamed(
    'confirm',
    queryParameters: {
      'isLogin': true,
    },
  );
```

but here when i want to get that parameter i need to parse that to type because queryParameters is <String, String> and queryParametersAll is <String, List> too .

```
GoRoute(
    name: 'confirm',
    path: 'confirm',
    builder: (context, state) {
      return AuthConfirmPage(
        isLogin: bool.parse(state.queryParameters['isLogin']!),
      );
    },
  ),
```

what is the correct way to solve this problem ? i dont want to get bool by convert string via bool.parse .

Answer (score 1):

When passing parameters as query parameters in a URL, the values are typically treated as strings.
When handling these query parameters, you'll need to parse and convert the values to the appropriate data types.

anyway if you don't need to use bool.parse, Following one is also possible

```
isLogin: state.queryParameters['isLogin']=='true',
```

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters always pass a string value. So you have to pass a string. But if you want to pass bool you can use extra.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class AuthConfirmPage extends HookConsumerWidget {
  static const route = '/auth-confirm';
  final bool isLogin;
  const AuthConfirmPage({super.key, required this.isLogin});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Appbar'),
      ),
      body: const Column(
        children: [],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then declare your route like this. Set a default value so that you won't get any null error.

```
    GoRoute(
      name: AuthConfirmPage.route,
      path: AuthConfirmPage.route,
      builder: (context, state) {
        return AuthConfirmPage(
          isLogin: bool.tryParse(
                  state.uri.queryParameters['isLogin']!) ??
              false,
        );
      },
    ),
```

and pass the query parameter like this

```
 context.pushNamed(
            AuthConfirmPage.route,
            extra: true,
            queryParameters: {
              'isLogin': 'true',
            },
          );
```

But if you want to pass bool instead of String then use extra and follow this procedure

```
       GoRoute(
          name: AuthConfirmPage.route,
          path: AuthConfirmPage.route,
          builder: (context, state) {
            return AuthConfirmPage(
              isLogin: state.extra as bool,
            );
          },
        ),

   context.pushNamed(
                AuthConfirmPage.route,
                extra: true,
              );
```